# certificate Installation in Mozilla and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, cryptojs, firefox-developer-tools, ejbca

how can i install a server generated browser certificate in Mozilla and Chrome using java script. ia have this method

```
( 
var certData = document.getElementById("certdata").value;
 window.crypto.importUserCertificates(null, certData, false);
 )
```

but it is outdated and it doesn't works.

Comment: What do you mean by "install"? Unless this is an addon it should never have that permission.

Comment: by install i mean to install the certificate received from CA as a result of certificate request made by client browser.the above mentioned method was valid for old browsers but this support has been disabled for latest browsers.i am looking for a method that could take the certificate response from server and installs it on my browser(mozilla and chrome)

Comment: i found the solution for this problem .u need to do is to out put http content-type as "application/x-x509-user-cert" the browser (Mozilla and chrome will get certificate automatically if they are with the corresponding private key) :)

Comment: Tariq, can I have an api which returns the certificate received from CA as string but setting its content-type as "application/x-x509-user-cert" ?

Comment: u can set its contect type mentioned but the type of data could be base64(string format).

Answer (score 2):

The solution mentioned in comments - using content type "application/x-x509-user-cert" - has [stopped working in Chrome since 2016](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/02/chrome-49-beta-css-custom-properties.html) (Chrome 49). This feature has been [deprecated](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=514767). The long-term alternative is to use the [WebCrypto API](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/), or a higher-level API based on it, like [PKI.js](https://pkijs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can not.

Take a look at fortofyapp.com for some middleware that enables this use case.